# BASS.NET PITCHSHIFT Effect doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, bass

I have tried other effects similar to this, but the `PITCHSHIFT` effect doesn't work. Why is it not being applied, and how can I fix it?

The code to create and play the `ch4` stream is in another function.

```
BASS_BFX_PITCHSHIFT pitch = new BASS_BFX_PITCHSHIFT();
pitch.fsemitones = 25;
int setPitch = Bass.BASS_ChannelSetFX(ch4, BASSFXType.BASS_FX_BFX_PITCHSHIFT,1);
Bass.BASS_FXSetParameters(ch4, pitch);
```

I got a return of `BASS_ErrorGetCode()`. It returns `BASS_OK`.

Comment: Why do you think your pitch isn't shifted? Have you tried changeing `1` into something bigger, like, a thousand?